# How can I locate position of letters from a list which contains there position?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers which refers to the position that they are in a string e.g

```
x=[1,3,5,9,2]
alphabet = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz #the string
print alphabet[:x]
```

I would like this to return to me 'bdfjc' (python starts at 0)

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=[1,3,5,9,2]
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #the string
r = "" # The string to print out at the end
for i in x:
    r += alphabet[i]
print r
```